# Jest Mock: Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to test a component but facing an error.

```
    Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

      39 |
      40 |     // Render the component
    > 41 |     const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(componentToTest.html)
         |                                              ^
      42 |
```

Full code:

Random.test.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { store } from '../../../redux/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Random from './Random'

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({ useDispatch: jest.fn() }))

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  useNavigate: jest.fn(),
}))

describe('<Random />', () => {
  let componentToTest = {
    title: 'Random: ',
    html: (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MemoryRouter>
          <Random />
        </MemoryRouter>
      </Provider>
    ),
  }

  test('Custom elements should mount and work', () => {
    render(componentToTest.html)
  })
  test('renders the user title correctly', () => {
    const dispatchMock = jest.fn()
    const navigateMock = jest.fn()

    // Mock the useAppDispatch and useNavigate hooks
    ;(useDispatch as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(dispatchMock)
    ;(useNavigate as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(navigateMock)

    // Render the component
    const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(componentToTest.html)

    // Assert that the clock icon is rendered
    expect(getByTestId('clock-icon')).toBeInTheDocument()

    // Assert that the user title is rendered correctly
    expect(getByText('test')).toBeInTheDocument()

    // Assert that the chevron right icon is rendered
    expect(getByTestId('chevron-right-icon')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Don't need to provide the component itself bcs, i've already tried an empty / newly created component, so component doesnt matter.

What i've tried so far is when i remove the lines;

```
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({ useDispatch: jest.fn() }))

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  useNavigate: jest.fn(),
}))
```

First test success but second's error is evolving into this:

```
  TypeError: _reactRedux.useDispatch.mockReturnValue is not a function

      35 |
      36 |     // Mock the useAppDispatch and useNavigate hooks
    > 37 |     ;(useDispatch as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(dispatchMock)
         |                                 ^
      38 |     ;(useNavigate as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(navigateMock)
      39 |
      40 |     // Render the component
```

Actually that is inverse evolving. Anyone faced this before?